# My Remotes Not Pruning And Are Still Red, Why?

Tags: git

I ran the command :

```
git branch -a
```

and I see

[image]

then I type

```
git remote prune origin
```

but I still see the same red remotes when I run the '-a' command. What's going on?

Comment: Can you show output of `git ls-remote origin`?

Comment: git remote prune origin removes references under refs/remote that are not there on your remote. If the branches being shown with git branch -a exist in your remote, git remote prune origin won't be able to remove them as they are still being referenced by their remotes.

If the branches from remote are removed, then try running git fetch followed by git remote prune origin. It should then clean up your local remote refs.

Comment: Red is the normal default color for active remote-tracking branches - it doesn't mean "deleted". You can change this if you like.